# Python adding layers of square based pyramids

Tags: loops, while-loop

I am trying to create a program that takes a user input, in this case 'i'. It then uses 'i' in order to count the number of layers in a square based pyramid. After that it counts the total number of blocks in the pyramid with 'i' layers.

The layers increase like this:

- Layer 1 - 1
- Layer 2 - 9
- Layer 3 - 25
- Layer 4 - 49
- Layer 5 - 81
- Layer 6 - 121

and so forth.

I have created the code which counts the number of blocks per layer but does not add the total. For example if i were to input '3' it would output 1,9,25 but I need it to output 35 which is the sum of those numbers.

Any help would be apreciated here is my code.

```
while True:
    i = input('Enter a number: ')
    i = int(i) #2
    while i >= 1: #2  
        i2 = i #2
        a = i - 1 #1
        b = a + i2 #3
        c = b**2   #9
        i = i - 1 #1
        print(c)
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, but are you just wanting to create a variable (maybe called count?) above the inner while loop, then add c to it each iteration, then print it after the loop?

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly! Something so simple aswell!

Answer (score 0):

Added count above the second while loop then added c to count and printed count after the while loop.

```
count = 0
    while i >= 1: #2  
        i2 = i #2
        a = i - 1 #1
        b = a + i2 #3
        c = b**2   #9
        i = i - 1 #1
        count = count +c
    print(count)
```